# A standalone webserver with document filtering support

Tags: file-synchronization, web-server

I'm looking for a webserver very similar to CouchDB, which stores its data as plain files and folders.

I need to:

- Get the directory content

  - with file name filtering support (similar to `startkey`, `endkey`, `sort` and `limit` [options of CouchDB](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.2.2-docs/ddocs/views/collation.html#string-ranges))
  - with long polling support
- Fetch a file

Is there any cross-platform (Windows and Linux) standalone webserver application for that purpose?

## Use Case

An application takes images and saves them into a folder. On another machine, I need to fetch those images efficiently and then push them to a database. It's basically `rsync` without keeping the fetched files on the destination.

Answer (score 0):

This goal can be achieved with `rsync` when the deleted files on the destination folder are appended to a file and `--exclude`d from synchronization.